# firebase: command not found in GitLab Runner

Tags: angular, firebase, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, firebase-hosting

Gitlab runner showing the error like

```
/bin/bash: line 116: firebase: command not found
```

my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: node:latest
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
stages:
  - setup
  - build
  - deploy
setup:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - npm install --legacy-peer-deps
    - npm install @angular/cli
    - npm i -g firebase-tools
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build --prod
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

How to fix this?. Is anthing wrong with my code?.

Answer (score 0):

This Particular Error means that you don't have the `firebase` globally!
try this hope it will help you!

```
image: node:latest
build:
  stage: build
  environment: 
    name: production
  script:
    - npm install --legacy-peer-deps
    - npm install @angular/cli
    - npm i -g firebase-tools
    - ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod
    - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

Thanks!
And Also You have to get the `$FIREBASE_TOKEN` by running this command `firebase login:ci`
Now you are good to go!